# Python Scipy, interpolation array to image

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have problem with my basic script which load image, then convert it to array, zooming by interpolation and should save zoomed image to file but this last line don't work. I have no idea how to fix it, i know that problem it is with zoomed array. I will be very glad for any help.

Script Code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x= misc.imread('img400x400.jpg')
x2= ndimage.zoom(x, 2, order=0)
#print x
#print x2
#plt.imshow(x)
plt.savefig(x2)
```

Output that I got:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "imgpolar.py", line 11, in
>   
>       plt.savefig(x2)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 561, in
>   savefig
>       return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1421, in
>   savefig
>       self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2220,
>   in print_figure
>       **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py",
>   line 517, in print_png
>       filename_or_obj, self.figure.dpi) TypeError: Object does not appear to be a 8-bit string path or a Python file-like object

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you probably only want to zoom along the first two axes of your image array (not the RGB axis, or you'll end up with an array of the wrong shape, `(nx, ny, 6)`). You can specify which axes to zoom as a tuple:

```
x2 = ndimage.interpolation.zoom(x, (2,2,1), order=0)
```

Secondly, you need to save the image using `ndimage.imsave`: `plt.savefig` expects a filename to save the current plot to (and there isn't one), not an array. So, try using:

```
misc.imsave(x2, 'interp.jpg')
```

Where `interp.jpg` is whatever you want to call your zoomed image.

Comment: Thank you! :) Do you know maybe how to use other interpolation way I mean other methods like hanning, hamming etc. ?

Comment: As far as I know, `ndimage.interpolation.zoom` just does spline interpolation. You might ask a new SO question to elicit a better answer on this...